# ValueError: number of bits must be greater than zero (python)

Tags: python, function, loops, random, simulation

I have tried to write a program that will simulate a game of Blackjack for x amount of times. It works, but only if x = 1...

This is my code for the program:

```
import random


def deck():

    deck_cards = []

    card = ["Ace of spades", 11]
    deck_cards.append(card)
    card = ["2 of spades", 2]
    deck_cards.append(card)
    card = ["3 of spades", 3]
    deck_cards.append(card)
    card = ["4 of spades", 4]
    deck_cards.append(card)
    card = ["5 of spades", 5]
    deck_cards.append(card)
    card = ["6 of spades", 6]
    deck_cards.append(card)
    card = ["7 of spades", 7]
    deck_cards.append(card)
    card = ["9 of spades", 8]
    deck_cards.append(card)
    card = ["9 of spades", 9]
    deck_cards.append(card)
    card = ["10 of spades", 10]
    deck_cards.append(card)
    card = ["Jack of spades", 10]
    deck_cards.append(card)
    card = ["Queen of spades", 10]
    deck_cards.append(card)
    card = ["King of spades", 10]
    deck_cards.append(card)
    card = ["Ace of hearts", 11]
    deck_cards.append(card)
    card = ["2 of hearts", 2]
    deck_cards.append(card)
    card = ["3 of hearts", 3]
    deck_cards.append(card)
    card = ["4 of hearts", 4]
    deck_cards.append(card)
    card = ["5 of hearts", 5]
    deck_cards.append(card)
    card = ["6 of hearts", 6]
    deck_cards.append(card)
    card = ["7 of hearts", 7]
    deck_cards.append(card)
    card = ["9 of hearts", 8]
    deck_cards.append(card)
    card = ["9 of hearts", 9]
    deck_cards.append(card)
    card = ["10 of hearts", 10]
    deck_cards.append(card)
    card = ["Jack of hearts", 10]
    deck_cards.append(card)
    card = ["Queen of hearts", 10]
    deck_cards.append(card)
    card = ["King of hearts", 10]
    deck_cards.append(card)
    card = ["Ace of clubs", 11]
    deck_cards.append(card)
    card = ["2 of clubs", 2]
    deck_cards.append(card)
    card = ["3 of clubs", 3]
    deck_cards.append(card)
    card = ["4 of clubs", 4]
    deck_cards.append(card)
    card = ["5 of clubs", 5]
    deck_cards.append(card)
    card = ["6 of clubs", 6]
    deck_cards.append(card)
    card = ["7 of clubs", 7]
    deck_cards.append(card)
    card = ["9 of clubs", 8]
    deck_cards.append(card)
    card = ["9 of clubs", 9]
    deck_cards.append(card)
    card = ["10 of clubs", 10]
    deck_cards.append(card)
    card = ["Jack of clubs", 10]
    deck_cards.append(card)
    card = ["Queen of clubs", 10]
    deck_cards.append(card)
    card = ["King of clubs", 10]
    deck_cards.append(card)
    card = ["Ace of diamonds", 11]
    deck_cards.append(card)
    card = ["2 of diamonds", 2]
    deck_cards.append(card)
    card = ["3 of diamonds", 3]
    deck_cards.append(card)
    card = ["4 of diamonds", 4]
    deck_cards.append(card)
    card = ["5 of diamonds", 5]
    deck_cards.append(card)
    card = ["6 of diamonds", 6]
    deck_cards.append(card)
    card = ["7 of diamonds", 7]
    deck_cards.append(card)
    card = ["9 of diamonds", 8]
    deck_cards.append(card)
    card = ["9 of diamonds", 9]
    deck_cards.append(card)
    card = ["10 of diamonds", 10]
    deck_cards.append(card)
    card = ["Jack of diamonds", 10]
    deck_cards.append(card)
    card = ["Queen of diamonds", 10]
    deck_cards.append(card)
    card = ["King of diamonds", 10]
    deck_cards.append(card)

    return deck_cards


def first_deal(initial_deck):

    new_deck0 = initial_deck
    new_dealer0 = 0
    new_hand0 = 0

    for i in range(2):

        card_h = random.choice(new_deck0)
        new_hand0 += card_h[1]
        new_deck0.remove(card_h)

        card_d = random.choice(new_deck0)
        new_dealer0 += card_d[1]
        new_deck0.remove(card_d)

    return new_deck0, new_hand0, new_dealer0


def bot_turn(new_deck1, new_hand1, new_dealer1):

    new_deck2 = new_deck1
    new_hand2 = new_hand1
    new_dealer2 = new_dealer1

    while new_hand1 <= 17:

        card_d = random.choice(new_deck2)
        new_hand2 += card_d[1]
        new_deck2.remove(card_d)

    return new_deck2, new_hand2, new_dealer2


def dealer_turn(new_deck2, new_hand2, new_dealer2):

    new_deck3 = new_deck2
    new_hand3 = new_hand2
    new_dealer3 = new_dealer2

    while new_dealer3 <= 16:

        card_d = random.choice(new_deck3)
        new_dealer3 += card_d[1]
        new_deck3.remove(card_d)

    return new_deck3, new_hand3, new_dealer3


def main():

    player_wins = 0
    dealer_wins = 0
    plays = 0

    for i in range(2):

        initial_deck = deck()

        new_deck1, new_hand1, new_dealer1 = first_deal(initial_deck)

        if new_hand1 == 21:

            player_wins += 1
            plays += 1
            continue

        elif new_hand1 > 21:

            dealer_wins += 1
            plays += 1
            continue

        elif new_dealer1 > 21:

            player_wins += 1
            plays += 1
            continue

        elif new_hand1 and new_dealer1 > 21:

            plays += 1
            continue

        new_deck2, new_hand2, new_dealer2 = bot_turn(new_deck1, new_hand1, new_dealer1)

        if new_hand2 == 21:

            player_wins += 1
            plays += 1
            continue

        elif new_hand2 > 21:

            dealer_wins += 1
            plays += 1
            continue

        new_deck3, new_hand3, new_dealer3 = dealer_turn(new_deck2, new_hand2, new_dealer2)

        if new_dealer3 > 21:

            player_wins += 1
            plays += 1
            continue

    print()
    print("You ran the simulation", plays, "times")
    print()
    print("You won", player_wins, "times")
    print()
    print("The dealer won", dealer_wins, "times")
    print()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

As you can see, the program is built up on three functions: the first deal, your (the bots) turn and the dealers turn. After every turn, the program will check to see if someone has busted or won. 
The problem I'm encountering reads as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ab50278\Portable Python\App\lib\random.py", line 249, in choice
    i = self._randbelow(len(seq))
  File "C:\Users\ab50278\Portable Python\App\lib\random.py", line 225, in _randbelow
    r = getrandbits(k)          # 0 <= r < 2**k
ValueError: number of bits must be greater than zero

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ab50278/Desktop/Python/Gy-arbete/Blackjack Sim.py", line 231, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/ab50278/Desktop/Python/Gy-arbete/Blackjack Sim.py", line 200, in main
    new_deck2, new_hand2, new_dealer2 = bot_turn(new_deck1, new_hand1, new_dealer1)
  File "C:/Users/ab50278/Desktop/Python/Gy-arbete/Blackjack Sim.py", line 143, in bot_turn
    card_d = random.choice(new_deck2)
  File "C:\Users\ab50278\Portable Python\App\lib\random.py", line 251, in choice
    raise IndexError('Cannot choose from an empty sequence')
IndexError: Cannot choose from an empty sequence
```

There seems to be something wrong with the way the program randomly chooses cards. But I don't know exactly what the problem is caused by.

I can't for the life of me figure out why it can't run the simulation more than one time (and all the other questions that stackoverflow recommends, that could have the answer to my problems are either not in python or a bit too complicated).

Hopefully I explained my problem good enough, but if you need to have a look at the rest of my code I'll edit my post accordingly. I really need help on this thing, and since is the first moderately complicated bit of coding I've ever done, I'm at a complete loss. Thank you for answering!

Comment: I can see there a few more flaws. I suggest you post the whole code somewhere.

Comment: Try something like this for generating your deck: `suits = ['diamonds', 'hearts', 'spades', 'clubs']`, `cards = 'Ace 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 Jack Queen King'.split()`, `deck = ['%s of %s' %  (card, suit) for card in cards for suit in suits]`. Think about what I did and remember: whenever your code looks repetitive, there is a better way to do it.

Comment: Yes, that would save some space. But would the way the deck is created really save me from getting errors?

Answer (score 0):

This error is thrown because you somehow provide empty list to random.choices. Try:

```
random.choice([])
```

and you will see the same error.

EDIT - after question edited

The error is indeed in the empty list provided to random.choice. It happens here:

```
def bot_turn(new_deck1, new_hand1, new_dealer1):

    new_deck2 = new_deck1
    new_hand2 = new_hand1
    new_dealer2 = new_dealer1

    while new_hand1 <= 17:

        card_d = random.choice(new_deck2)
        new_hand2 += card_d[1]
        new_deck2.remove(card_d)
```

You have the typo there, you end up in the unlimited loop - change the while line to:

```
while new_hand2 <= 17:
```

Now you can also run the main loop more twice.

Anyway, your case is a good example for debugging. I suggest you to use some IDE like PyCharm and learn how to debug your code (its easy :)

Comment: I will try and format the code. meanwhile, do you know the solution to the problem?

Comment: Is the formatting fixed now? I tried indenting a couple of lines.